# MOSFET RCA source switcher

Tags: audio, audio-adapters, audio-quality

I was advised on another Stack Exchange [site](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/52169/is-distortion-clipping-spikes-from-changing-an-input-source-dangerous-for-a-p) to get a MOSFET RCA source switcher, which shouldn't introduce any noise when switching sources. Unfortunately I was not able to find examples of such devices. I need an RCA source switcher to switch between two different preamp sources for my power amplifier.

So, does anyone know what a MOSFET RCA source switcher is and could recommend such device?
Recommendations from users who use them in their audio systems would be most appreciated, also your impressions if these devices affect the audio quality in any way.